# Use AWS CDK to set up a CloudFrontWebDistribution to have GET /subdirectory server /subdirectory/index.html from an S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cdk

I'm using the https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/tree/master/typescript/static-site AWS CDK example to configure a Cloudfront + S3 bucket to serve a static site.

It does not seem like requests to GET /subdirectory responds with /subdirectory/index.html though. How would one use the CDK to configure Cloudfront + S3 to serve /subdirectory/index.html?

Comment: It looks like I need to do a Lambda@Edge function. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/implementing-default-directory-indexes-in-amazon-s3-backed-amazon-cloudfront-origins-using-lambdaedge/

I'm not yet sure how to implement this using CDK but I will respond back once I find out how...

Comment: An easier and cost effective way is to use S3 website endpoint and define index.html as index document, it'll automatically redirect /subdirectory to /subdirectory/index.html. However , it is a bit less secure (you can't use OAI).

Comment: Yes, I would need to have https. It seems like I would need Cloudfront.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a solution to create a Lambda@Edge function, which performed the Url Rewrite.

https://briantakita.com/posts/static-https-websites-using-aws-cdk-cloudfront-and-s3

The source code is contained in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/btakita/2572df4fae440dc065eb888f53316bdd).

Answer (score 3):

if you don't want to use lambda, you can redirect errors to index.html which is how you are supposed to host SPA on CloudFront using

```
errorConfigurations: [
       {
          errorCode: 403,
          responseCode: 200,
          responsePagePath: '/index.html',
          errorCachingMinTtl: 10
       }
   ]
```

for more info see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-cloudfront.CfnDistribution.CustomErrorResponseProperty.html